# Apostrophe throwing off input value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of names. for example "Davis,Jordan" , "O'Keefe,Bret", "King,James", etc..

I loop through this array and assign these values to the value of an input field. These input fields are inside a table cell. See below.

```
var name="<input name='name"+x+"' id='name"+x+"' readonly value='"+array3[i]['Assoc_Name']+"'>";
```

The problem is with names such as "O'Keefe,Bret", the apostrophe in the last name throws off the value and displays it as so:
[image]
However when I use console.log(array3[i]['Assoc_Name']) it prints out the entire name fine as O'Keefe,Bret.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rewrite it switching the ' to "

```
var name='<input name="name'+x+'" id="name'+x+'" readonly value="'+array3[i].Assoc_Name+'">';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also escape your `"` in the html

```
var name = "<input name=\"name"+x+"\" id=\"name"+x+"\" readonly value= \""+array3[i].Assoc_Name+"\">";
```

Answer (score 0):

In `HTML`, a single quote is escaped as `&#39;`.

So, the HTML-compatible version of O'Keefe is:

```
O&#39;Keefe
```

If you use this as your string in your `javascript`, you will not need to escape single quotes in your script.

Comment: I have seen this used before, but not feasible with my data. The array contains thousands of names, and the array has the potential to change on a daily basis, as it is a live feed from a database. Therefore, searching for specific instances of an single quote and editing those strings would be more of a pain than the answer given by xkcd149